# KShell background task not showing in jobs

Tags: shell, ksh, background-process

I've written a simple KShell script to kick off a background task

```
#/bin/ksh 
#startMonitoring

./detectFile /usr/local/data/testFile > fileHistory &
```

I run it with the following command

```
startMonitoring
```

When I run jobs I get no results, but the command is running and shows up in ps:

> 512232  pts/0  0:34 /bin/ksh ./detectFile /usr/local/data/testFile

Why can't I see the item in jobs, and how can I change my script so it does show up in jobs?

Comment: Should this get moved to ServerFault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jobs` command only looks in the current shell. Scripts are run in their own shell. If you source your script instead, then `jobs` will show it:

```
$ . startMonitoring
$ jobs
[1] +  Running                 . startMonitoring
```